# How do relation multiplicities work?

Tags: alloy

I'm using this simple model and the evaluator to study relation multiplicities. The evaluator dialogue demonstrates a situation that I find puzzling.

```
sig A {}
sig B {}

pred show {}
run show

Evaluator dialogue:

univ

{A$0, A$1, B$0, B$1, B$2}

B->A

{B$0->A$0, B$0->A$1, B$1->A$0, B$1->A$1, B$2->A$0, B$2->A$1}

B lone -> A

{B$0->A$0, B$0->A$1, B$1->A$0, B$1->A$1, B$2->A$0, B$2->A$1}

// Although the two relations seem to be identical,

B->A in B->A 

true

// but

B->A in B lone -> A 

false
```

What makes the two products different in answering 'B->A in B->A' and 'B->A in B lone -> A'?

Comment: Reviewing my post it seems the evaluator is mistaken in answering the query B lone -> A. As I understand, this expression requires that at most one member of B is mapped to each member of A, which is obviously not satisfied by the relation the evaluator gave.

Comment: It seems my expectation was misplaced. As the evaluator might produce various answers to random queries like 'B lone -> A', it's surely not an error but a developer decision that B -> A is returned.